# Symfony2 MySql: Fetch array and get JSON array without column names

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, symfony

I am trying to figure out how to get JSON array with following format

```
  [
     ["2016-02-26","5190","1253","425","123"],
     ["2016-02-27","5209","1114","521","214"],
     ["2016-02-28","5142","1425","412","156"],
     ["2016-02-29","5523","1365","632","198"],
     ["2016-03-01","5125","1452","523","152"],
     ["2016-03-02","5000","1245","741","286"]
   ]
```

But currently I am getting

```
  [{"date":"2016-02-26","visitors":"5190","registered":"1253","downloaded":"425","sticky_activity":"123"},
   {"date":"2016-02-27","visitors":"5209","registered":"1114","downloaded":"521","sticky_activity":"214"},
   {"date":"2016-02-28","visitors":"5142","registered":"1425","downloaded":"412","sticky_activity":"156"},{"date":"2016-02-29","visitors":"5523","registered":"1365","downloaded":"632","sticky_activity":"198"},
   {"date":"2016-03-01","visitors":"5125","registered":"1452","downloaded":"523","sticky_activity":"152"},
   {"date":"2016-03-02","visitors":"5000","registered":"1245","downloaded":"741","sticky_activity":"286"}]
```

Here is my function, if it's gonna help

```
  public function dataAction(Request $request){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $connection = $em->getConnection();

    $sqlQuery = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, \"%Y-%m-%d\") as date,visitors, registered, downloaded, sticky_activity
                  FROM engagement";

    $statement = $connection->prepare($sqlQuery);

    $statement->execute();
    $queryResult = $statement->fetchAll();

    return new JsonResponse($queryResult);
}
```

Comment: Use `array_values()`

Comment: i guess `GROUP_CONCAT()` is what you are looking for, unfortunatly i cant go any further

Comment: @malcolm no, it didn't help. I am still getting column names in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return this:

```
return new JsonResponse(array_map('array_values', $queryResult));
```

By the way you should also avoid direct SQL calls in favor of [DQL](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) or [query builders](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html). These are good practices while using Doctrine. Its goal is to avoid SQL as much as possible.

Comment: Yeah, I would use DQL, but 'engagement' is not a class, it's just a table